# Next.js npm run dev does not start development server

Tags: web, next.js

I am doing some next.js work, mainly learning and came across a website which provides landing pages for websites (https://startuplanding.redq.io/).

I have downloaded one of their templates to play around with, it's the next.js version. I have tried following the documentation on the website (https://startuplanding-documentation.vercel.app/getting-started) to open the dev server and view the site in the browser by using npm run dev however I get the following error message:

npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

I have used npm run and get the following message:

Lifecycle scripts included in desktop@1.0.0:
test
echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Not too sure how to get past this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

I tried using mp run dev to run the development server and expected to work as normal since I have done other next.js projects and nothing like this has happend.

Instead I got this error message:

npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

I have used npm run and get the following message:

Lifecycle scripts included in desktop@1.0.0:
test
echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Comment: Looks like the `package.json` of your current working directory does not have `dev` in the scripts section. If you look at the other projects, the `package.json` should contain `"scripts": {` followed by `"dev": "next dev",`.

Comment: Hello, have had a look at package.json and it does have "dev": "next dev", in the scripts section.

Just did some checking myself, so within the scripts section in package.json I tried to run the dev script and it has produced an error message that nextconfig.js failed to load so I think the issue is within that file.

Comment: Here is how my nextconfig.js file looks like:

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfiguration = {
  target: 'serverless', //will output independent pages that don't require a monolithic server. It's only compatible with next start or Serverless deployment platforms (like ZEIT Now) — you cannot use the custom server API.
};

module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages], nextConfiguration);

Comment: What is the exact error message for nextconfig.js failing to load? You can edit your post to include that. Actually I am wondering if you're trying to run it from another folder, and that other folder happens to include an unrelated file with the same name package.json

Comment: I fixed the nextconfig.js error, it said it was failing to load and I had a look at it's content and compared it to a typical nextconfig.js file and it was different so I changed it to the default content and fixed that error but now I am getting this error:

    error - ./src/analytics/index.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-ga'
> 1 | import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
  2 | 
  3 | export const initGA = () => {
  4 |   console.log('GA init');

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/pages/_app.js

Comment: You haven't got `react-ga` in node_modules. If you have  `package.json` correctly configured you can run `npm i` to get it. If the entry is missing from package.json, you can add it by `npm install react-ga`

Answer (score 0):

If you run:

```bash
node -p "process.arch"
```

does the result match your architecture (32/64 bits)?

output :

```bash
arm64
```

ref:"https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43202"